# Scrollbar displaying but not scrolling the dynamically created combobox widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have created a canvas, scrollbar on a label frame. Using a button, dynamically creating the combobox widgets on the canvas. But the scrollbar **not** scrolling through the dynamically created.

```
  from tkinter import *      
  from tkinter import ttk

  root = Tk()      
  root.geometry("1366x705+0+0")


  ExtRole_Dest_LF = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text='ExternalRoles', width =600)
  ExtRole_Dest_LF.place(relx=0.225, rely=0.113, relheight=0.376, relwidth=0.264)

  canvas=Canvas(ExtRole_Dest_LF,bg='#FFFFFF', height = 110, width = 335, scrollregion=(0,0,500,800))
  canvas.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'news')
  canvas.grid_propagate(0)
  canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))


  vbar=Scrollbar(ExtRole_Dest_LF,orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
  vbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1,  sticky='ns')
  canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)

  global System_Dest_row
  System_Dest_row = 1
  def fn_SystemDest():
      global System_Dest_row
      System_Dest_col = 0
      System_Dest_cb = ttk.Combobox(canvas, values=['a','s','d','g'], width=15)
      System_Dest_cb.grid(row=System_Dest_row, column=System_Dest_col, padx=10, pady = 5)
      deletebutton = Button(canvas, text="X")
      deletebutton.grid(row=System_Dest_row, column=System_Dest_col + 1, padx=10, pady = 5)
      System_Dest_row += 1

  AddButton = Button(root, text = 'Add', command =fn_SystemDest )
  AddButton.grid(column = 3,row = 3)

  root.mainloop()
```

Can I make scrollbar to scroll through the dynamical combobox widgets

Can I grt solution in any otherway to scroll the combobox widgets on LabelFrame/Frame

Answer (score 1):

You can't scroll things added to a canvas with `grid`. A canvas can only scroll items added to it with one of the `create_` functions.

Comment: Can I get scroll through the combobox widgets on Lable Frame without canvas. I mean any alternative solution to scroll